# Objective-C: Convert minutes to time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I'm having an issue converting minutes since midnight to a correct time. It works fine until i reach noon. At which point the time becomes `0:45AM` and anything after noon is blank. Am I missing something in my format?

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:m"];
    NSLog(@"Minutes %i",minutes);
    NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", (minutes / 60), (minutes % 60)];
    NSLog(@"time: %@",time);
    NSDate *formatTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:time];
    NSLog(@"formatTime %@",formatTime);
    dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"H:mma"];
    NSString *newTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:formatTime];
    NSLog(@"NewTime: %@",newTime);
    dateFormatter = nil;
```

Log

```
2012-01-25 15:12:23.194 MyApp[43875:f803] Minutes 480
2012-01-25 15:12:23.194 MyApp[43875:f803] time: 8:0
2012-01-25 15:12:23.195 MyApp[43875:f803] formatTime 1970-01-01 15:00:00 +0000
2012-01-25 15:12:23.196 MyApp[43875:f803] NewTime: 8:00AM
2012-01-25 15:12:23.197 MyApp[43875:f803] Minutes 495
2012-01-25 15:12:23.197 MyApp[43875:f803] time: 8:15
2012-01-25 15:12:23.198 MyApp[43875:f803] formatTime 1970-01-01 15:15:00 +0000
2012-01-25 15:12:23.199 MyApp[43875:f803] NewTime: 8:15AM
2012-01-25 15:12:23.200 MyApp[43875:f803] Minutes 765
2012-01-25 15:12:23.200 MyApp[43875:f803] time: 12:45
2012-01-25 15:12:23.201 MyApp[43875:f803] formatTime 1970-01-01 07:45:00 +0000
2012-01-25 15:12:23.201 MyApp[43875:f803] NewTime: 0:45AM
2012-01-25 15:12:23.203 MyApp[43875:f803] Minutes 480
2012-01-25 15:12:23.203 MyApp[43875:f803] time: 8:0
2012-01-25 15:12:23.204 MyApp[43875:f803] formatTime 1970-01-01 15:00:00 +0000
2012-01-25 15:12:23.204 MyApp[43875:f803] NewTime: 8:00AM
2012-01-25 15:12:23.205 MyApp[43875:f803] Minutes 495
2012-01-25 15:12:23.206 MyApp[43875:f803] time: 8:15
2012-01-25 15:12:23.206 MyApp[43875:f803] formatTime 1970-01-01 15:15:00 +0000
2012-01-25 15:12:23.207 MyApp[43875:f803] NewTime: 8:15AM
2012-01-25 15:12:23.208 MyApp[43875:f803] Minutes 555
2012-01-25 15:12:23.209 MyApp[43875:f803] time: 9:15
2012-01-25 15:12:23.209 MyApp[43875:f803] formatTime 1970-01-01 16:15:00 +0000
2012-01-25 15:12:23.210 MyApp[43875:f803] NewTime: 9:15AM
2012-01-25 15:12:23.211 MyApp[43875:f803] Minutes 630
2012-01-25 15:12:23.211 MyApp[43875:f803] time: 10:30
2012-01-25 15:12:23.212 MyApp[43875:f803] formatTime 1970-01-01 17:30:00 +0000
2012-01-25 15:12:23.212 MyApp[43875:f803] NewTime: 10:30AM
2012-01-25 15:12:23.214 MyApp[43875:f803] Minutes 690
2012-01-25 15:12:23.214 MyApp[43875:f803] time: 11:30
2012-01-25 15:12:23.215 MyApp[43875:f803] formatTime 1970-01-01 18:30:00 +0000
2012-01-25 15:12:23.215 MyApp[43875:f803] NewTime: 11:30AM
2012-01-25 15:12:23.217 MyApp[43875:f803] Minutes 765
2012-01-25 15:12:23.217 MyApp[43875:f803] time: 12:45
2012-01-25 15:12:23.217 MyApp[43875:f803] formatTime 1970-01-01 07:45:00 +0000
2012-01-25 15:12:23.218 MyApp[43875:f803] NewTime: 0:45AM
2012-01-25 15:12:32.506 MyApp[43875:f803] Minutes 840
2012-01-25 15:12:32.507 MyApp[43875:f803] time: 14:0
2012-01-25 15:12:32.507 MyApp[43875:f803] formatTime (null)
2012-01-25 15:12:32.508 MyApp[43875:f803] NewTime: (null)
```

EDIT:
I am using Munid's Edit 2 below and it works well except it seems to be subtracting 7 hours from `newDate` when I run it through the `dateFormatter`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    //dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    NSDate *midnight = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
    NSLog(@"midnight %@",midnight);
    NSDate *newDate = [midnight dateByAddingTimeInterval:minutes*60];
    NSLog(@"new date %@", newDate);
    //[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];
    NSString *newTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate];
    NSLog(@"Time: %@", newTime);
    dateFormatter = nil;
```

will log

```
2012-01-25 16:15:03.418 MyApp[44721:f803] midnight 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
2012-01-25 16:15:03.418 MyApp[44721:f803] new date 1970-01-01 08:00:00 +0000
2012-01-25 16:15:03.419 MyApp[44721:f803] Time: 01:00 AM
2012-01-25 16:15:03.420 MyApp[44721:f803] midnight 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
2012-01-25 16:15:03.420 MyApp[44721:f803] new date 1970-01-01 08:15:00 +0000
2012-01-25 16:15:03.420 MyApp[44721:f803] Time: 01:15 AM
2012-01-25 16:15:03.421 MyApp[44721:f803] midnight 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
2012-01-25 16:15:03.422 MyApp[44721:f803] new date 1970-01-01 12:45:00 +0000
2012-01-25 16:15:03.422 MyApp[44721:f803] Time: 05:45 AM
2012-01-25 16:15:03.423 MyApp[44721:f803] midnight 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
2012-01-25 16:15:03.424 MyApp[44721:f803] new date 1970-01-01 08:00:00 +0000
2012-01-25 16:15:03.424 MyApp[44721:f803] Time: 01:00 AM
2012-01-25 16:15:03.425 MyApp[44721:f803] midnight 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
2012-01-25 16:15:03.425 MyApp[44721:f803] new date 1970-01-01 08:15:00 +0000
2012-01-25 16:15:03.426 MyApp[44721:f803] Time: 01:15 AM
2012-01-25 16:15:03.427 MyApp[44721:f803] midnight 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
2012-01-25 16:15:03.427 MyApp[44721:f803] new date 1970-01-01 09:15:00 +0000
2012-01-25 16:15:03.427 MyApp[44721:f803] Time: 02:15 AM
2012-01-25 16:15:03.428 MyApp[44721:f803] midnight 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
2012-01-25 16:15:03.429 MyApp[44721:f803] new date 1970-01-01 09:30:00 +0000
2012-01-25 16:15:03.429 MyApp[44721:f803] Time: 02:30 AM
2012-01-25 16:15:03.430 MyApp[44721:f803] midnight 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
2012-01-25 16:15:03.431 MyApp[44721:f803] new date 1970-01-01 10:30:00 +0000
2012-01-25 16:15:03.431 MyApp[44721:f803] Time: 03:30 AM
2012-01-25 16:15:03.432 MyApp[44721:f803] midnight 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
2012-01-25 16:15:03.432 MyApp[44721:f803] new date 1970-01-01 11:30:00 +0000
2012-01-25 16:15:03.433 MyApp[44721:f803] Time: 04:30 AM
```

Comment: From my painful experience, I believe NSLog formats dates using the system timezone (NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]). NSDateformatter will interpret dates for the timezone it is configured with, which I believe is @"UTC" by default. This probably accounts for the 7 hour difference that you are seeing. When I am not interested in absolute time (which is what dates are meant to represent) I make sure all calculations are done in one timezone, typically I set them all to UTC. I avoid using NSLog to see dates, because it just creates confusion unless you are paying close attention to this detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, maybe your method with format strings is a little bit too involved. Don't forget, that the `NSLog` output also needs to be formatted, otherwise you will get a different locale and time zone, so these values are not reliable for checking if your logic is right.

The simple solution is to use the fact that `NSTimeInterval` is in seconds. Thus:

```
NSDate *midnight; // the date you want, at 0:00 am
NSDate *newDate = [midnight dateByAddingTimeInterval:minutes*60];
```

**EDIT:**

Also, I checked your code - you can fix it by changing the format strings. The problem was that the date formatter got confused with the minute having 1 or 2 digits.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
for (NSInteger minutes = 495; minutes < 1000; minutes +=60) {
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
    NSLog(@"Minutes %2i",minutes);
    NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2i:%2i", (minutes / 60), (minutes % 60)];
    NSLog(@"time: %@",time);
    NSDate *formatTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:time];
    NSLog(@"formatTime %@",formatTime);
    dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];
    NSString *newTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:formatTime];
    NSLog(@"NewTime: %@",newTime);
}
dateFormatter = nil;
```

**EDIT2:**

Expanding on the code above as requested:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSDate *midnight = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
for (NSInteger minutes = 495; minutes < 1000; minutes +=60) {
    NSDate *newDate = [midnight dateByAddingTimeInterval:minutes*60];
    NSLog(@"newDate: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate]);
}
dateFormatter = nil;
```

Comment: I edited my answer to both correct your code and expand on my approach.

Comment: Edit1 doesn't seem to fix the problem and edit 2 changed the times to start at 1am instead of 8am.

Comment: edit 2 looks good and is showing correct in the correct newDate in the logs but it looks like when we run it through the formatter it messes the time up.

Comment: when I do an NSLog on the newDate it looks perfect once I run it through the dateFormatter it is -7 hours from the newDate. I am MST which is -7 hours but I don't have the dateFormatter locale set. I took that out to see if it would fix it but no luck. Any ideas? I will edit my original post.

Comment: Ok figured it out. The time for NSDate is GMT and dateFormatter was MST. I set dateFormatter to GMT and all is well `[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that handles the time zone and the time display for the user's locale correctly:

```
void doMinutes(NSUInteger minutes) {
    static const NSUInteger minutesInDay = 60 * 24;

    if (minutes >= minutesInDay) {
        minutes = minutes % minutesInDay;
    }

    //Create a new date at midnight GMT
    NSDate *newDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:minutes * 60];
    NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [fmt setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [fmt setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [fmt setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    NSLog(@"minutes: %ld, new date: %@", minutes, [fmt stringFromDate:newDate]);
    [fmt release];
    [newDate release];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *p = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    doMinutes(480);
    doMinutes(765);
    doMinutes(840);
    doMinutes(30);
    doMinutes(1430);
    [p release];
}
```

Log output:

```
minutes: 480, new date: 8:00 AM
minutes: 765, new date: 12:45 PM
minutes: 840, new date: 2:00 PM
minutes: 30, new date: 12:30 AM
minutes: 1430, new date: 11:50 PM
```

Log output when locale is set to United Kingdom:

```
minutes: 480, new date: 08:00
minutes: 765, new date: 12:45
minutes: 840, new date: 14:00
minutes: 30, new date: 00:30
minutes: 1430, new date: 23:50
```

Comment: @Jim This answer was created after I marked the above answer complete. I also posted in the comment of that answer the solution to the timezone issue